# Backtracking maze in C, with obstacles

Tags: c, recursion, backtracking, maze

I need to solve a maze using backtracking method.
My maze has 0 listed as a wall, 1 listed as an empty cell, 2 is for visited, 3 for dragon.
Dragons are basically obstacles that I can go through BUT I need to choose the path with the LEAST dragons.
So far I can solve the maze and mark a path, but I can't seem to think of a relatively simple way of finding the path with the least dragons.
Do note we just started coding with C in my uni (so far I've only done java/bash/a bit of python), so I'm really new to C and algorithms in general.

Code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IMPOSSIBLE (N*N+1)

int counter=0;

enum {WALL,EMPTY,VISITED,DRAGON,N};
int printMaze(int maze[N][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            printf("%d ",maze[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int solveMaze(int maze[N][N], int i, int j)
{
    if (maze[i][j] == WALL){ return 0; } // If [i][j] are currently a wall (0).
    if (maze[i][j] == VISITED) { return 0; } // If [i][j] are currently a mark (2).
    if (maze[i][j] == DRAGON) { counter++; }
    maze[i][j] = VISITED; // Mark current spot with (2).
    if (i==N-1 && j==N-1) { return 1; } // reached the end (N-1,N-1) - (3,3) incase N is 4.
    if (   ((i < N-1) && solveMaze(maze,i+1,j)) || ((i > 0) && solveMaze(maze,i-1,j)) || ((j < N-1) && solveMaze(maze,i,j+1)) || ((j > 0) && solveMaze(maze,i,j-1)) ) { // checking index-out-bounds + recursively going around the maze
        return 1;
    }
    maze[i][j] = EMPTY;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int maze[N][N] = { {1,1,3,3},
                       {3,0,1,1},
                       {3,0,0,1},
                       {1,3,3,1} };

    int solved = solveMaze(maze, 0, 0);
    if (solved)
    {
        printMaze(maze);
        printf("Amount of dragons passed through in the maze: %d\n",counter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No solution, %d\n",IMPOSSIBLE);
    }
}
```

I tried creating a counter that counts the amount of dragons on the way, but I guess I'm not fluent enough in recursions to make it go in every available path and choose the best one.

Comment: This is a minimum-cost pathfinding problem, for which [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), for example, is well suited.  But Dijkstra's does not perform backtracking *per se*.  Nor is it usually implemented recursively, though it's unclear whether recursion is a requirement for this exercise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. We didn't go over Dijkstras algorithm yet so I'm assuming I need to solve this without using it.
Also, recursion is a requirement here, yea I'm a bit confused myself on how to approach this...

Comment: You could nevertheless employ some of the aspects from Dijkstra's algorithm, such as maintaining for each visited node a reference to a predecessor node along a least-(so far discovered)-cost path to that node.  Or perhaps just the cost (number of dragons) on the best path through the node that has been discovered so far.

Comment: One way to do it would be to recursively explore *all* of the paths, or at least until you find one with zero dragons, or otherwise can prove that there is no path cheaper than the cheapest one you have discovered.

Comment: Also, to properly implement backtracking you need to restore each node to its original state when you backtrack out of it.  The code in the question does not do that properly for nodes that initially contain dragons.

Comment: Is the output of the program presented exactly what the assignment requires?  That is, are you required to print both a representation of the maze showing the chosen path, in the form demonstrated by the code, and the number of dragons along the path?  Because the problem would be a bit easier if you needed only to print the minimum number of dragons.

Comment: Well, now that you mention it. I need to return the minimum number of dragons on a correct path...replacing the path with 2's or even printing it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to understand the idea of recursively traversing the tree with backtracking.  The issue is that you need to find not just *a* path, but the one with the least cost -- that is, the fewest dragons.  That means that in general, you can't stop with the first path you find.  You need to keep going until you can be sure that there's no better path.

Here's one way to do it:

- Maintain a variable to track the number of dragons along the best path discovered so far.  Initialize it to something larger than the value that can appear along any path -- your `IMPOSSIBLE`, for example, or `INT_MAX`.  This is separate from the number of dragons so far encountered along the path you are currently exploring.
- Perform a recursive traversal much like you are already doing, except

  - Fix the example code's problems with restoring state (node contents and `counter` value) when you backtrack out of a dragon node.
  - Stop exploring any given path when the number of dragons encountered along it equals the number along the best path discovered so far.
  - In light of the previous, you can be certain that whenever you discover a path that reaches the exit, that path has fewer dragons than the best path previously discovered, if any.  Update the variable tracking the best number of dragons accordingly.  Note that this does not necessarily end the search, but it may reduce the search space that remains to be explored.

Comment: Thanks aloooot for the extensive explanation! I figured it out with your help, thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is to imagine the maze as a 3 dimensional graph instead of 2D. You have the triplet (i, j, number_of_dragons) define the nodes of the graph. Note that this may in extreme case mean the number of nodes are N^4. Thus you will need an array with size [N][N][N*N] to store if the given node is visited (note that dragons and walls can still be stored in a [N][N] array). To get the minimal path from source to target, simply iterate over the the values of [target.x][target.y][i] and return the minimum i for which you have visited the node.

I can suggest a better solution using min path graph algorithm like Dijkstra, but it seems this is out of scope for the question.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer.
Any chance you can show me an example on how to do this? I'm pretty lost.